# Is it possible to get user email from MS Teams with a Bot using SDK4?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using C# and Bot Framework SDK4 and need to get the user email from a 1:1 chat with my bot. Is it possible? All I can seem to get is ID and full name.

I have tried the things listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context
but the teamsContext is just returning null.

```
ITeamsContext teamsContext = turnContext.TurnState.Get<ITeamsContext>();

string incomingTeamId = teamsContext.Team.Id;
string incomingChannelid = teamsContext.Channel.Id;
string incomingTenantId = teamsContext.Tenant.Id;
```

So is it even possible to get the user email from the current user chatting with the bot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can! Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#fetching-user-profile-or-roster-in-personal-or-group-chat), you just do the same as if you were getting the team roster, but use the conversation id, instead.  For example:

```cs
var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials("<yourAppId>", "<yourAppPassword>");
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), credentials);
var conversationId = turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id;
var userInfo = await connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(conversationId );
```

Note: I tried using the [`Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet) package to do this, but couldn't get it to work. Had to use the `connector` method above.

Comment: The "Get single member details" section from "the docs" link worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private async  Task GetUserProfile(TurnContext context,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    BotFrameworkAdapter botAdapter = (BotFrameworkAdapter)context.Adapter;           
    var conversation = await botAdapter.GetConversationMembersAsync(context, cancellationToken);
}
```

You can visit - [How get user email from MS Teams with a Bot using SDK4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727804/how-get-user-email-from-ms-teams-with-a-bot-using-sdk4)