# TEAMS bot in node.js: 'Authorization has been denied for this request' in CreateConversation method

Tags: node.js, authorization, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a TEAMS node.js bot running locally (with ngrok). I receive messages from TEAMS client and echo works

```
context.sendActivity(`You said '${context.activity.text}'`);
```

Now I want to send a 1to1 message to this user, but I receive

```
Error: Authorization has been denied for this request
```

when creating a conversation.

My code:

```
   var sUserId  = "29:1shb_5I6CkkerBVq4qPqcv5dGwDfkXx11Jbjc1UnGCIv"
   var sServiceUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/";
   var sTenantId = "942369d2-208e-438b-894c-0d0e1510cf61";
   var credentials = new BotConnector.MicrosoftAppCredentials({
        appId: "xxxxxxx",
        appPassword: "yyyyyyyy"
    });
    var connectorClient = new BotConnector.ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: sServiceUrl });

    const parameters = {
        members: [ { id: sUserId } ],
        isGroup: false,
        channelData:
        {
            tenant: {
                id: sTenantId
            }
        }
    };
    var conversationResource = await connectorClient.conversations.createConversation(parameters);

// I get the error here, next is not executed
    await connectorClient.conversations.sendToConversation(conversationResource.id, {
        type: "message",
        from: { id: "xxxxxxx" },
        recipient: { id: sUserId },
        text: 'This a message from Bot Connector Client (NodeJS)'
    });
```

appId & appPassword are valid (from .env file), if they are wrong I can not receive messages from TEAMS client

I have the same code to create a conversation in a .NET bot  and it works for me:

```
  var parameters = new ConversationParameters
   {
       Members = new[] { new ChannelAccount(sUserId) },
       ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
       {
            Tenant = new TenantInfo(sTenantId),
       },
   };

   retValue = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters);
```

What is wrong in my node.js code?

Thanks,

Diego

Answer (score 2):

Have you trusted the service? It don't think so based on your code, and it's a classic cause of 401 in your case.

In node.js, do the following:

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
```

If you want more details around that, have a look to the documentation about getting 401 when sending proactive messages [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors)

And also this SO answer about Teams and Proactive messaging, in particular last block.
[Proactive messaging bot in Teams without mentioning the bot beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496329/proactive-messaging-bot-in-teams-without-mentioning-the-bot-beforehand)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Nicolas R. It seems to be the problem. Maybe it is a basic problem, but I am new in node.js... When I add your line, I get a 'MicrosoftAppCredentials is not defined' error... How can I add the required reference?

Comment: Take a look at your code: `var credentials = new BotConnector.MicrosoftAppCredentials...` . Must be the same origin

Comment: Thanks, i did not see it. Now I get  different error: "TypeError: source.on is not a function". I open a new question, since it is a different problem