# Questions regarding Bot sample 16.proactive-messages (nodejs SDK)

Tags: botframework

I have referred [this new sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages) of 4.x Sdk for proactive messages. This definitely a good start but I have few concerns based on my use case.

1. Can this sample be used for a Bot in ms teams channel ? out bot is has ms team channel and its used in production by 9000+ users today.

the reason I am confused because I came across another document [bots-conv-proactive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) which is specially talking about proactive-messages for ms teams only. Does this mean repo example wont work in teams ?

2. Repo example highlights *"This project has a notify endpoint that will trigger the proactive messages to be sent to all users who have previously messaged the bot"*

Is there any trick to make it work for users who have not used the bot in ms teams before and we would like to use repo example to send proactive messages. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this sample be used for a Bot in ms teams channel ? out bot is has ms team channel and its used in production by 9000+ users today.

Yes. It can be used for the Teams Channel. Regarding the number of users, just be sure you host your bot appropriately so that it can handle that many potential concurrent users.

> I came across another document bots-conv-proactive which is specially talking about proactive-messages for ms teams only. Does this mean repo example wont work in teams ?

Both samples work in Teams. The second one you linked is just Teams-specific, whereas the first applies to all Botframework Channels.

> Is there any trick to make it work for users who have not used the bot in ms teams before and we would like to use repo example to send proactive messages. ?

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#obtain-necessary-user-information), you can send to any user, so long as you have their **unique ID** and their **tenant ID**, which you can get:

- By [fetching the team roster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#fetching-the-team-roster) from a channel your app is installed in.
- By caching them when a user [interacts with your bot in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel). **Note: This is how the Botframework sample does this**
- When a users is [@mentioned in a channel conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#-mentions) the bot is a part of.
- By caching them when you [receive the conversationUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition) event when your app is installed in a personal scope, or new members are added to a channel or group chat that

[Here's a How-To for messaging without prior interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496329/proactive-messaging-bot-in-teams-without-mentioning-the-bot-beforehand/57499608#57499608)

I'd also like to point out a key paragraph in the docs that will save you some headache:

> When creating proactive messages you must call `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl`, and pass in the service URL before creating the ConnectorClient you will use to send the message. If you do not, your app will receive a `401: Unauthorized` response.