# Get all team members when bot is installed in MS Teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to implement Proactive Messaging with a MS Teams bot. According to the docs i have to get a `conversationReference` before sending any message to the user so I implemented the `onMembersAdded` event listener as follows:

```
class TeamsBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.onConversationUpdate(async (context, next) => {
      this.addConversationReference(context);
    });

    this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
      const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
      for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
        if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
          this.addConversationReference(context);
        }
      }
      await next();
    });
  }
```

The problem is that I get notified only of the user that is installing the app even tough my Team (and channel) has plenty of members:

[image: team members]

How do I get conversation references for every team member once the bot is installed?

Comment: Put in an answer below, let me know if anything's not clear. I'm presuming you don't just want to proactively message into the channel, and rather that you're trying to message each user individually...

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve, send 1:1 messages to every user with a scheduled task, can you provide more information about the Graph and it's implementation using the Bot Framework SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note the difference between the users in a Team and the conversation reference between a user and a bot. What the docs are -trying- to say is this:

1. When you bot is added to the team, you can get a list of the *users in the team*.
2. You can use that *list of users* to look up in your *own database* the conversation references you need to *have already* for those users in order to messages. This is because those are references to *separate* conversations - the bot is in the Team/Channel and has *that* reference, but the 1-1 chats the bot wants to use to message the users personally are each separate individual chats.
3. If you *don't* yet have a conversation reference for any/all of those users, you need to get them. That means the user needs to either (a) install the bot themselves or you need to (b) [install it for them via the Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The docs, imo, don't really explain that well - they assume that by enumerating the list of users you'll be getting -actual- conversation references straight away, and/or that you might be able to initiate the conversation using the bot framework itself.

Comment: Ok, I get it, in order to start new 1:1 conversations I have to get the app installed individually for each user using the Graph but how can I accomplish that using JS? The docs you linked aren't clear enough

Comment: What do you mean by "JS"? You mean Node? Or something client-side?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the JavaScript SDK with NodeJS

Comment: Have you tried the SDK? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript

Answer (score 0):

**To start conversation in channel** -
I think you are looking for something like this  - see 3 point [MessageAllMembers](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/560994a556824a45b79f434d782b9804e8b74795/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot#interacting-with-the-bot). Try the sample available - [Teams Conversation Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/560994a556824a45b79f434d782b9804e8b74795/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot). (see for [code snippet](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/560994a556824a45b79f434d782b9804e8b74795/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot/bots/teamsConversationBot.js#L172-L190))

You can use [TeamsInfo.getPagedMembers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs-adaptive-teams/getpagedmembers?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) to get members details in the team

UPDATE -
**To start 1:1 conversation** -
We have this implemented with C# in [Company Communicator App template](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator). Company communicator's [code snippet](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/blob/207013db2ad64ac5c3d365fd4db1a25fd2d703cf/Source/CompanyCommunicator.Common/Services/MicrosoftGraph/TeamWork/AppManagerService.cs#L33) for app installation.

To install it first, refer the document shared by @Hilton Giesenow, [JavaScript snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#tabpanel_1_javascript) and follow [create authProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS).

Have a look at this [method](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/blob/207013db2ad64ac5c3d365fd4db1a25fd2d703cf/Source/CompanyCommunicator.Common/Services/Teams/Conversations/ConversationService.cs#L70) where we are creating a 1:1 conversation in Company Communicator. ([JavaScript method ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/botframeworkadapter?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#createConversationAsync_string__string__string__string__ConversationParameters___context__TurnContext_____Promise_void__)).

Comment: this won't start a 1:1 conversation but continue the conversation on the channel instead

Comment: Hello, In order to start conversation, you need to install it first, refer the document shared by @Hilton Giesenow, [JavaScript snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#tabpanel_1_javascript) and follow [create authProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS). Updated my answer.

Comment: Similar to your question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084661/ms-teams-bot-js-create-conversation).