# Trouble writing a proactive message Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm currently trying to send a proactive message with my Microsoft Teams bot by using the following example code that I see online:

```js
var address =
{
    channelId: 'msteams',
    user: { id: userId },
    channelData: {
        tenant: {
            id: tenantId
        }
    },
    bot:
    {
        id: appId,
        name: appName
    },
    serviceUrl: session.message.address.serviceUrl,
    useAuth: true
}

var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
msg.text('Hello, this is a notification');
bot.send(msg);
```

The only change made is that I use TeamsMessage instead of a regular Message because I get errors saying that Message isn't a class which has also confused me. The problem when I run the code is that it tells me that my bot doesn't have a function named 'send'. My bot extends the TeamsActivityHandler class. My question is how do I fix this issue?

Comment: You don't seem to have a conversation reference. Messages can't be sent by bots without the user first interacting with the bot giving you a conversation reference. Installing the application into teams will give you this initial reference.  Try and follow this example https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages

Answer (score 0):

You need the user’s unique ID and tenant ID to send a proactive message. Typically, these are obtained from a team context, either by fetching the team roster or when a user interacts with your bot in a channel. Please check documentation on how to [send proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#starting-a-personal-conversations).

Here is the source code for [Node.js sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/master/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.ts) for Proactive Messages.

Comment: I've been able to acquire both ID's for the message. The problem is I don't know how to send the information. When I try 'bot.send' it says that the 'send' method doesn't exist and I've seen examples use 'session.send' but I don't know how to get the session object.

Comment: Is it just a new Session object I create?

Comment: Can you please provide more context on the shared code? like what instance is "bot" ans also Can you please share which document you are referring?

Comment: The example using a session is the link you sent me which is [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/master/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.ts). The bot itself is a class that extends the TeamsActivityHandler class in the bot sdk (v4). What I'm attempting to do is given only a user ID from the team, personally message that ID when an event happens.

Comment: I can get the tenant ID and User ID but the problem is I don't know how to send a message to that user's address in version 4 of the botbuilder module.

Comment: I'm trying to send a proactive message without having any previous conversation reference.

Comment: I found the solution to my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496329/proactive-messaging-bot-in-teams-without-mentioning-the-bot-beforehand/57499608#57499608)