# How to get the kind of info in "General channel"?

Tags: office365, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We can't use bot events to get the channel creator, nor use MS Graph to subscribe to these events, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284205/how-to-get-member-added-event-or-channel-created-event-in-ms-teams/58352477#58352477)

I found some info showed in "General" Channel, like [channelInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXpxY.png)

I also tried the graph API, `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{group-id-for-teams}/channels/{channel-id}/messages`,

but it is not channel message at all.

Is it possible to fetch it, then analyze it to get the expected info?

Comment: Could you add sample code you tried so far?

Comment: Could you please take a look at [Get Channel Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)? If this is not the information you are looking for,  please let us know what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help! *Note: I tried the link Trinetra-MSFT included, but it only seems to return normal messages*

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you want to hear, but this currently isn't possible. You can [add a feature request through the Teams UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public), though, if you'd like.

---

If you really, really want to struggle through this to get it working, you can F12 in Chrome and watch the Network tab when opening a Channel in Teams for Web. You can view the events:

[image]

Here's a snippet of that request:

[image]

However, it would be very difficult to do on a production level; since the API isn't public, it's likely to change and isn't really meant to be used. I really, really recommend against it.