# How get user email from MS Teams with a Bot using SDK4?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

We deployed our bot application on the MS-Teams channel so for Authorization purposes, we required the emailId of the **MSTeams** logged-in user, so initially, We are facing an issue for getting emailId from the Activity object. After doing some analysis, we found one solution, that emailId  will get from the **BotFrameworkAdapter** class in ms-bot v4 using C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private async  Task GetUserProfile(TurnContext context,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    BotFrameworkAdapter botAdapter = (BotFrameworkAdapter)context.Adapter;           
    var conversation = await botAdapter.GetConversationMembersAsync(context, cancellationToken);
}
```

We will get the following response from the **conversation** variable

{
    "id": "UserConversationId",
    "name": "Full Name of the user",
    "aadObjectId": null,
    "role": null,
    "objectId": "Object Id",
    "givenName": "FirstName",
    "surname": "LastNamr",
    "**email**": "**OrganizationEmailId**",
    "userPrincipalName": "UserPrincipalName",
    "tenantId": "TenantId",
    "memberRole": "user"
}